# How to get a dictionary of top words and the number of their occurrences using Lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net, lucene, word-count

I have a project which uses Lucene.net (latest version) to index a file containing large (2 million) lines of text using the StandardAnalyzer.

I am writing each line to the index as a single document; using the index generated I now want to get a dictionary of each word and its total count across all the documents.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Luke.NET](http://luke.codeplex.com/) does this. Here's the function from it's source that should help get you on your way:

```
public static TermInfo[] GetHighFreqTerms(Directory dir,
                                          Hashtable junkWords,
                                          int numTerms,
                                          String[] fields)
{
    if (dir == null || fields == null) return new TermInfo[0];

    IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(dir, true);
    TermInfoQueue tiq = new TermInfoQueue(numTerms);
    TermEnum terms = reader.Terms();

    int minFreq = 0;

    while (terms.Next())
    {
        String field = terms.Term.Field;

        if (fields != null && fields.Length > 0)
        {
            bool skip = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            {
                if (field.Equals(fields[i]))
                {
                    skip = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (skip) continue;
        }

        if (junkWords != null && junkWords[terms.Term.Text] != null)
            continue;

        if (terms.DocFreq() > minFreq)
        {
            tiq.Add(new TermInfo(terms.Term, terms.DocFreq()));
            if (tiq.Size() >= numTerms)              // if tiq overfull
            {
                tiq.Pop();                   // remove lowest in tiq
                minFreq = ((TermInfo)tiq.Top()).DocFreq; // reset minFreq
            }
        }
    }

    TermInfo[] res = new TermInfo[tiq.Size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
    {
        res[res.Length - i - 1] = (TermInfo)tiq.Pop();
    }

    reader.Dispose();

    return res;
}
```